# Improve RabbitMQ throughput

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm using RabbitMQ and Celery for a project and I've reached a bottleneck.

My architecture is as follows:

- 1 RabbitMQ node
- between 1 and 7 nodes who will read from RabbitMQ via Celery

I started some performance measurements and by pre-populating Rabbit with 200k messages, the node performs about 600msg/sec.

Starting two nodes with the same pre-populated queue, I get a little under 600msg/sec for both nodes.

Adding more node with the same scenario leads to a drastic loss in throughput, reaching under 400msg/sec with 7 nodes.

I've started to add some settings (some even from the RabbitMQ site) but it lead to no improvement.

My current settings configuration is

```
[   {kernel, [
    {inet_default_connect_options, [{nodelay, true}]},
    {inet_default_listen_options,  [{nodelay, true}]}   ]},   {rabbit, [
    {tcp_listeners,[{"0.0.0.0", 5672}]},

    {vm_memory_high_watermark, 0.6},

    {tcp_listen_options, [binary,
                          {packet, raw},
                          {reuseaddr, true},
                          {backlog, 128},
                          {nodelay, true},
                          {exit_on_close, false},
                          {keepalive, true},
                          {sndbuf, 32768},
                          {recbuf,32768}
                          ]}   ]} ].
```

I've been reading blogs and posts by users and they mention a lot bigger throughput than what I am achieving. There are mentions of 100k/sec while I'm barely getting 2.8k/sec.

Any thoughts on what I can do to improve my throughput?

Comment: you're using rabbitmq as the broker, but not as the result backend, right?

Comment: That's correct. One node is the rabbit broker, 7 nodes get messages from the broker and based on what they receive they do some actions on other nodes. (but now I'm testing the limits so the final part is skipped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to have a separate queue for each consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [transient queues](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#using-transient-queues) by setting the following in `celeryconfig.py`:

```
CELERY_DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE = 'transient'
```

This prevents RabbitMQ from saving to disk which can improve throughput

Also if you're using RabbitMQ as your result backend you'll probably get better performance by switching to Redis.